# USB D+ D- not present

Tags: usb, embedded

So I am designing my first pcb and using an AT32ucb µc. It says in the data sheet it supports usb interface but on the pin-out listings and functions I can only find usb-id and usb-VBOF. So what am meant to use for the data in and out? I'm thinking like the tx and rx of the usart perhaps but would like clarification on the issue and to know if I am totally off.datasheet below pinout starts around page 7.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc32059.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the pinout diagrams there are dedicated DP and DM pins near the VBUS.